# Does Azure App Service automatically restart when Azure Key Vault renew the certificate?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault, azure-appservice

My Azure App service is loading a certificate from the Azure Key Vault. I have set cert as auto-renew in key vault. My appservice is loading the new certificate, whenever Keyvault renews the cert.

I know AppService keep syncing with Azure Key Vault in a background process. How does it happen when AppService finds there is a renewed certificate in Key Vault? Does appservice loads new renewed cert in the Current User and restart the AppService?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does it happen when AppService finds there is a renewed certificate in Key Vault?

The Web App service runs a background job that periodically (once a day ) that syncs all App Service certificate. Hence when you rotate or update a certificate, sometimes the application is still retrieving the old certificate and not the newly updated certificate.  This is because the job has not run to sync the certificate resource. **It will automatically update the hostname bindings for the certificate in App Service within 48 hours.**

> Does app service loads new renewed cert in the Current User and restart the AppService?

It will automatically updates the certificate in App Service without causing any downtime to your apps.